# How many different colorings of the faces of a cube can you produce with 8 colors?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A First Course in Abstract Algebra (7th Edition) Chapter S.17, Problem 4E

Wooden cubes of the same size are to be painted a different color on each face to make children's blocks. How many distinguishable blocks can be made if 8 colors or paint are available? Hint: X must be a set of functions from a set with 6 elements to a set with 8 elements.

Let $A= (1,2,3,4,5,6)$ which corresponds to sides in the cube and $B= (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)$ which corresponds to painting on the sides through $F\colon A\to B$. Then $X= \{F \colon  A\to B\}$. This means that $X$ consists of functions from the set $A$ to the set of $B$.

1) Is it really ALL functions that are included in X? why?

2) How the group G acts on X? i.e. what is function $gF\colon A\to B$ if $F\in X$? I want to understand how the group G acts on such a functions set X. I hope that I get an answer from your experience with thanks.

Comment: It is much better if you pick a title for your question that describes it. A full bibliographical reference is only useful for that for the few people that have the  book at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I am a new member with you.

Comment: ...and **the author** is...?

Comment: John B. Fraleigh

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**:

- The set $X$ of functions from $A$ to $B$ corresponds to possible paintings of a single cube. Think of the defining property of a function. Every element in the domain (face of a cube) must go to a single element in the codomain (color). This means that you assign to each face of your cube a single color, which is what you wanted.
- If you number the faces of a cube (as we did through the set $A$), different colorings may lead to indistinguishable cubes. Think of the symmetries of the cube. If it helps, do first the 2 dimensional case: in how many different ways can you color the four edges of a square in the plane with a given number of colors?
- To formalize this last point, think of symmetries of the cube as relabeling the faces. In this way, the group of symmetries of the cube $G$ acts on your set of colorings $X$. Then use this action to describe what is the relevant number of colorings that you get (if two colorings are int he same orbit, can you distinguish between them?).

Comment: For painting any one of the face we have 8 choices of colours available with you.

Now for painting second face we have only 7 choices of colour available with we because of the eight colours available was utilised for paunting the first face.

Similarly for painting third face we have 6 vhoices of colour available with us.

And so on for the last face we have 3 choices of colour available with us.

Therefore total ways in which we can paint the cube is

8×7×6×5×4×3 = 20160

Hence 20160 blocks are available with us.

Comment: I think the first question has solved. But I did not understand exactly the second question. 2) How the group G acts on X?

Comment: Consider a simpler example: you have only two faces 1 and 2, and only two symmetries, namely the identity (which takes face 1 to face 1 and face 2 to face 2) and the permutation of the faces (face 1 goes to face 2 and face 2 to face 1). Now you have a coloring (a function which sends face 1 to green and face 2 to red, say). Then the identity sends this coloring to itself and the permutation sends it to the function which assigns face 1 to (the original color of the image of face 1 under the permutation) red and similarly face 2 to green.

Comment: A thousand thanks for your useful comments. Does that mean that G acts faithfully or transtivit on X?

Comment: Faithfully: yes, any non trivial permutation of the faces of the cube in your group G (your group G does not contain all permutations) changes some face and you can always find a coloring which paints the preimage (under that permutation) of that face and the face itself in different colors. Transitively: what would it mean for the action to be transitive? Only one orbit. This means only one possible coloring. You can get different colorings of course (1 green 5 red and 2 green 4 red), so it is not a transitive action.

Comment: A thousand thanks Mr. Perdo. I think everything is now clear. G acts  faithfully on X because of N= (e).